# Create multiple texts files from data in an original text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, text

I have an original text file with 100 rows and 40 columns of data. 
I would like to write an individual text file for each data row of the original text file.

I can only work out how to do it the long way:

```
Data = loadtxt('Data.txt')

Row1 = Data[0,:]

np.savetxt('Row1.txt', [Row1])

Row2 = Data[1,:]

np.savetxt('Row2.txt', [Row2])

Row3 = Data[2,:] etc....
```

Is there a way of using a loop to make this process quicker/do it all at once so I can avoid doing this 100 times?

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
with open('Data.txt') as f:
    for line in f.
    line_out = f.readlines(): 
    with open(line + '.txt','w') as fout:
    fout.write(line_out)
```

This doesn't work but I can't work out what the code should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  This should give you files with names corresponding to each line number:

```
counter = 0
with open("sampleInput.txt",'rU') as f:
     for i in f:
        newFileName = 'newFile_'+str(counter)
        outFile = open(newFileName,'w')
        outFile.write(i)
        outFile.close()
        counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider fileNames.txt contain all the words for creating multiple .txt files.

```
f = open('fileNames.txt', 'r+')
for line in f:
    if '\n' in line:
         line = line[:-1]                 #assuming /n at the end of file
    new = open("%s.txt"%line,"w+")
    new.write("File with name %s"%line)   #content for each file.
    new.close()
```

New files will not be created if \n is present in the string. Hence avoid such conditions.
If fileNames.txt contains---> frog four legs
Then three files named frog.txt four.txt and legs.txt will be created.